# Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3 Facing this issue in flutter while running App in Android emulator

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, build.gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I try everything. I means Youtube, ChatGpt , google , posts in groups, ask from others, but i can't find any solution of this. problem. The Problem is when i create the app in Android studio. I can run it every platform only it is not running in android Studio. I run it on web it is running but when i run the same app on android studio it issues me this error

Comment: Did you run it with --stacktrace? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download build tools version 30.0.3 and platform-30 SDK if you're using it to compile. Check your File>Project Structure and download the required one (30.0.3) using Tools>SDK Manager.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This one works. Thank you so much for helping